# getting error while adding web_reg_save_param_ex from steps toolbox in loadrunner

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am getting error while adding web_reg_save_param_ex from steps toolbox in loadrunner,`"the step is not supported in current script loadrunner"`.
[image]

Can we solve this problem ?
Regards

Nikhil Kamboj

Comment: Which version of LoadRunner/VuGen are you using? Which protocol(s) are included in the script?

Comment: The version I am using is Vugen 12.57 built 0311 and using Web Http/HTML protocol.

Comment: Try upgrading your VuGen installation to the latest version 12.62

Comment: you mean to say this problem is with version 12.57. .We are working on client network and we don't have privileges to update by our on.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but I can help you through SO only if you use the current version (i.e. 12.6X). If you need support for 12.57 you will have to open a support ticket.

Comment: You can try sending the script to VuGen feedback email. It is found under the Help menu in VuGen